# If I sudo execute a Bash script file, will all commands inside the Bash script be executed as sudo as well?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sudo

I want to write an automated post-installation script in Bash (called `post-install.sh`, for instance). The script will automatically add and update repositories, install and update packages, edit config files, etc.

Now, if I execute this script, for instance with `sudo post-install.sh`, will I only be prompted for a `sudo` password once, or will I need to enter the `sudo` password on each invocation of a command inside the script, that needs `sudo` permission? In other words, do the commands inside the bash script 'inherit' the execution permissions, so to speak?

And, if they indeed *do*, is there still a possibility that the `sudo` permissions will time out (if, for instance, a particular command takes long enough to exceed the `sudo` timeout)? Or will the initial `sudo` password entrance last for the complete duration of whole script?

Comment: You may be interested to check out some tools specifically designed for this task. 3 common ones are: Puppet, chef, and ancible.

Comment: @spuder, and for larger-scale, enterprise-level architecture and security of your configuration management, you can use CFEngine 3.  (Not for the faint of heart, nor for one-off commands.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> **Q#1:** Will I only be prompted for a sudo password once, or will I need to enter the sudo password on each invocation of a command inside the script, that needs sudo permission?

Yes, once, for the duration of the running of your script.

**NOTE:** When you provide credentials to `sudo`, the authentication is typically good for 5 minutes within the shell where you typed the password. Additionally any child processes that get executed from this shell, or any script that runs in the shell (your case) will also run at the elevated level.

> **Q#2:** is there still a possibility that the sudo permissions will time out (if, for instance, a particular command takes long enough to exceed the sudo timeout)? Or will the initial sudo password entrance last for the complete duration of whole script?

No they will not timeout within the script. Only if you interactively were typing them within the shell where the credentials were provided. Every time `sudo` is executed within this shell, the timeout is reset. But in your case they credentials will remain so long as the script is executing and running commands from within it.

*excerpt from sudo man page*

> This limit is policy-specific; the default password prompt timeout for the sudoers security policy is 5 minutes.

Comment: The answer to Q1 is "No, you will not be prompted again."

Comment: @dannysauer - read his Q again. I'm saying Yes to being prompted for password only once!

Comment: The question says "is it a or b", and just saying "yes" didn't make it clear if it was "yes, a" or "yes, b".  Just trying to clarify things for future readers. :D

Comment: @dannysauer - see update.

Comment: @slm : Now if I want to run some of the commands in that script without `sudo`.How can I do that?

Comment: @Thushi - since you're now elevated you could do `su -l user1 -c "cmd1; cmd2"` inside your script. Your Q would probably warrant a new Q though, IMO.

Comment: This new question would be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522341/identify-user-in-a-bash-script-called-by-sudo . `sudo -u $(logname) <command>` should work.

Answer (score 17):

`bash` and all of its child processes will run with superuser permissions. So you will not need to re-enter a password for commands in your bash script.

The `sudo` timeout only applies to (later) separate invocation of `sudo`. It would not affect your already running bash process, or any of its descendants.

Answer (score 3):

These answers are all probably correct. However, this is not the generally-used way (as far as I am aware) to create bash scripts that require `sudo` permissions. Generally, at the top of the script you assume it hasn't been run with `sudo` permissions and instead call `sudo -v` yourself (which will prompt the user for their password) to 'set up' a `sudo` 'session'. You can either `echo` some explanatory text before the prompt, or override `sudo`'s own prompt with the `-p` switch, to let the user know you need `sudo` access for some commands.

Then, in your script you should be fine to call `sudo` on the commands that require it (and only those commands that require it) without further password requests. If you think a certain group of commands that run together in your script (regardless of their own use of `sudo`) will extend beyond the sudo timeout, you can call `sudo -v` in the middle in order to issue a kind of 'keep-alive' the `sudo` 'session'.

If the `sudo` 'session' does happen to expire during the script, the user will simply be asked for their password the next time you issue a sudo command in the script.

Comment: Say that one of the steps of the script is building a whole new linux kernel, which can take say two hours. Keeping the session alive could be a challenge, how'd you deal with that?

Comment: You can't. But next time you call `sudo -v` it'll ask the user for their password again. Not the worst issue in my opinion. Maybe to be helpful, making the user aware of the mechanism might be handy.

Comment: The inverse of this is to require the user to call the script with sudo per the other answers, and then `sudo -u $SUDO_USER` to make all non-root requiring commands run un-elevated. Sadly it adds more code, but is the only reliable way to perform root things in a long running process.

Comment: I guess I should clarify, another other way to do this would be to call sudo once at the beginning of the script to put a temporary file into `/etc/sudoers.d` using `visudo -c -f /tmp/tempsudoers` to ensure the file is  valid before copying it into place, and then remove that file once done (using a trap on exit/error to ensure the escalation can't be abused). The most safe and secure implementation would only allow your user to run the specific commands in your script with specific arguments without a password using `NOPASSWD` by storing each command/arguments into an array to build the file.

Comment: Somewhat late coming back to @Gauthier here but it would appear that I was wrong when I said you can't keep a `sudo` session alive if a given single task takes longer than the timeout. I came across this technique the other day in Mathias Bynens's dotfiles repo: `while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &` - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos#L13